# 隔離スコープのパラメータが同期されない

Tags: typescript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

開発環境は
Angular1.5
AngularBootstrap
TypeScript
です。

AngularbootstrapのDatepickerPopupをディレクティブでラップしています。
カスタムディレクティブで展開したHTMLから、
ng-clickで隔離スコープのbooleanを切り替えるだけのスコープ内関数を呼び出します。

```
this.scope = {};
this.templateUrl = "<div ng-include='uri'></div>";
this.link = (scope: IExtendedScope) => {
    scope.toggle = () => {
        scope.show = !scope.show;
    };
    scope.show = false;
}
```

hoge.html

```
is-open="show" datepicker-open="show" ng-click="toggle()"
```

隔離スコープのbooleanで表示、非表示を切り替えますが、AngularBootstrapのDatepickerPopupの機能で、ポップアップの外をクリックしても非表示になります。

このとき、隔離スコープのパラメータはfalse(ポップアップ非表示)になりますが、それ以降クリックすると、
パラメータ"show"は切り替わりますがポップアップは非表示のままとなります。

ただ、

```
 ng-click="show=!show"
```

とすることで、表示、非表示が行えるようになります。

上記事象について、詳しくわかる方がいたら何が起きているのか教えてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

詳細がわからないため推測になりますが、以下のどちらかではないでしょうか。

1. 異なるスコープでshowが定義されており、scope.toggleによる切り替えで期待したスコープのshowの値が変更されていない
2. DatepickerのshortcutPropagationの設定が考慮されていない

補足：
1.については作成されているカスタムディレクティブなどの詳細情報を追記されると原因がわかるかもしれません。
2.はBootstrapの[Datapickerのページ](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker)を参照してください。
クリックイベントが伝播されて表示/非表示の処理が連続して実行されている可能性があります。

Comment: shotrcutPropagetionはDatepickerのパラメータでしたので、回答を少し修正しました。1.の可能性があると考えた理由は`ng-click="show=!show"`とすると動くという記載があったため**想定外**のスコープが作られているのではないかと考えた次第です。datepicker-openのディレクティブ（おそらくカスタムディレクティブだと思っています）の詳細について追記いただければもう少し踏み込んで考えられるのですが、2が原因でなかった場合は詳細を追記されることをご検討ください。

Comment: 記載漏れの実装が原因で動作していませんでした。実際の実装は、template=<div ng-include="uri">していました。いろいろ調べたところ、ng-includeは子スコープを新しく作るようで、toggle()で変更していたのは子スコープのshow変数であったことが原因のようでした。is-open="$parent.show"とすることで解決しました。